# How to switch alert to regular message in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change Dan Abraham's code and want to switch alert to paragraph. Just trying to get some understanding of React.

React:

```
 function FancyBorder(props) {
   return ( <div className={'FancyBorder FancyBorder-' + props.color}> {props.children} </div> ); }

 function Dialog(props) {
   return (  <FancyBorder color="blue"> <h1 className="Dialog-title"> {props.title} </h1> <p className="Dialog-message"> {props.message} </p>
  {props.children} </FancyBorder> ); }

 class SignUpDialog extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) { 
     super(props);
       this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
       this.handleSignUp = this.handleSignUp.bind(this);
       this.state = {login: ''}; }

     render() {
        return ( <Dialog title="Mars Exploration Program" message="How should we refer to you?">
    <input value={this.state.login} onChange={this.handleChange} /> <button onClick={this.handleSignUp}> Sign Me Up! </button> </Dialog> );
  }
 handleChange(e) { this.setState({login: e.target.value}); }

 handleSignUp() { alert(`Welcome aboard, ${this.state.login}!`); }
 }

 ReactDOM.render( <SignUpDialog />, document.getElementById('root') );
```

Comment: To what "alert" do you refer to? There is none in the code snippet shared.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: What is "paragraph"?

Comment: Can you clarify, are you trying to display some text in a <p> tag on the page versus simply alerting some text? Why not revert it back to what you had previously and render `this.state.login` into a <p> tag in the render function? Or have I misunderstood and you are trying to do something else?

Comment: Yes, to <p> tag. it is" handleSignUp() { alert(`Welcome aboard, ${this.state.login}!`); }
 }".

Comment: By clicking button, instead of alert, it should be in a paragraph. I am trying to go around it and missed something.

Comment: You mean hier?
<p className="Dialog-message"> {props.message} </p>

Comment: it is in "<button onClick={this.handleSignUp}> Sign Me Up! </button>". Instead of alert it should give a paragragh under "Sign Me Up!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a piece of state to handle toggling the `login` to be displayed, and place the logic to set the toggle value in `handleSignUp`. Below the button conditionally render `this.state.login` if the toggle value is true.

```
class SignUpDialog extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSignUp = this.handleSignUp.bind(this);
    this.state = { login: "", showLogin: false }; // <-- add toggle state
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Dialog
        title="Mars Exploration Program"
        message="How should we refer to you?"
      >
        <input value={this.state.login} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <button onClick={this.handleSignUp}> Sign Me Up! </button>
        {this.state.showLogin && (
          <p>Welcome aboard, {this.state.login}!</p> // <-- conditional render
        )}
      </Dialog>
    );
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ login: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSignUp() {
    this.setState({ showLogin: true }); // <-- toggle state
  }
}
```

[image: Edit zen-darkness-7rhv4]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
function FancyBorder(props) {
  return (
    <div className={"FancyBorder FancyBorder-" + props.color}>
      {" "}
      {props.children}{" "}
    </div>
  );
}

function Dialog(props) {
  return (
    <FancyBorder color="blue">
      {" "}
      <h1 className="Dialog-title"> {props.title} </h1>{" "}
      <p className="Dialog-message"> {props.message} </p>
      {props.children}{" "}
    </FancyBorder>
  );
}

class SignUpDialog extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSignUp = this.handleSignUp.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      login: "",
      paragraphText: ""
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Dialog
        title="Mars Exploration Program"
        message="How should we refer to you?"
      >
        <input value={this.state.login} onChange={this.handleChange} />{" "}
        <button onClick={this.handleSignUp}> Sign Me Up! </button>{" "}
        <p>{this.state.paragraphText}</p>
      </Dialog>
    );
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ login: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSignUp() {
    this.setState({
      paragraphText: `Welcome aboard, ${this.state.login}!`
    });
  }
}
```